# How can i remove gnome-settings-daemon from indicators applications?

Tags: indicator, gnome-panel

I have a desktop configuration in the indicator applications to choose the desktop preferences, but i dont know how to disable it.

[image]

I know i can use the blacklist in `.config/indicators`. But actually i didn't manage to disable it.

Comment: Ok I manage to resolve it. I only have to disable the option inside the program (dont show monitors in the panel). I was looking for a solution more complicated.

Comment: you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Roland Taylor. I tried but I could not, because the system doesnt allow me to answer me before 8 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that an answer has been found.  However, I wanted to ask if this issue could have been reconciled using **gconf-editor**.  Under Apps/gnome-settings-daemon/xrandr, there is a setting (checkbox) for show_notification_icon.  After some experimentation, that seems to work on my system.

[image]